# NuxtJS3 (BETA/RC): Can't establish firebase connection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, types, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am currently implementing Firebase to my NUXT 3 Project with VUE and TS.

I did set everything up inside my firebase console and successfully logged in with my credentials inside the project itself

( `firebase login, firebase init`)

However, if I know create a plugin for Firebase under /plugins/firebaseAuth.client.ts and enter needed information and more, I am not able to establish a connection to my project.

At least I'm not receiving any feedback inside the console, I neither see an error or the logged Firebase object. Did I miss something?

I tried to use my .env for the variables and as direct string too.

firebaseAuth.client.ts

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    const config = useRuntimeConfig()

    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: 'xxxxxxx',
        authDomain: 'xxxxxxxx',
        projectId: 'xxxxxxxx',
        storageBucket: 'xxxxxx',
        messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxx',
        appId: 'xxxx',
        measurementId: 'xxxx',
    }

    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    console.log(app, 'APP')
})
```

nuxt.config.js

```
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import { NaiveUiResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers'
// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    build: {
        transpile: ['vueuc'], // fix dev error: Cannot find module 'vueuc'
        quiet: true,
    },
    vite: {
        plugins: [
            Components({
                resolvers: [NaiveUiResolver()], // Automatically register all components in the *components* directory
            }),
        ],
        // @ts-expect-error: Missing ssr key
        ssr: {
            noExternal: ['moment', 'naive-ui', '@juggle/resize-observer', '@css-render/vue3-ssr'],
        },
    },
    runtimeConfig: {
        firebaseApiKey: '',
        firebaseAuthDomain: '',
        firebaseProjectId: '',
        firebaseStorageBucket: '',
        firebaseMsgId: '',
        firebaseAppId: '',
        firebaseMeasurementId: '',
    },
})
```

Comment: I found the Issue: Look at your project hierarchy !! Mine was under src/plugins instead of regular root plugins folder. My TS files inside didn't get touched the whole time. Look here: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/plugins/